# question on execute ssis package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I developed ssis project on my local machine, extracting data from mysql db to sql server 2008. Everything works fine. Now i move the package, the .dtsx file, to the server which is a 64bit window 2008 box, it stops working. The problem is that package default to sqlserver driver instead of mysql drive. I have to move the whole project to the server from local machine and open the project to make it pick up mysql driver, then it will work. Is there a way i can develop on my loca machine but run on the server without having to open the project to pick up the right driver? thanks

Comment: Has the MySQL Driver been installed on the production server?

Comment: To manage your deployments efficiently you need to look at using Package Configuration files, reference by environment variables.